# BluePrism.BPCoreLib.InvalidValueException: Server configuration 'Default' is not defined

Tags: blueprism

when i tried starting the Blueprism server service, it throws an error below.
 [Service.msc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eZ7p.png)

In Application Log(Event Viewer) , below error occurs
[Event Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWpWA.jpg)

I just need to Configure the blue prism Server so I need to start the blue prism server.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the body of your question, it appears you haven't attempted to configure your server profile to connect to the Blue Prism Database.

Launch `BPServer.exe` (in the Blue Prism installation directory) and edit the Default profile with your server's connection information.